# How to run preloader before page starts loading VUE.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, preloader

So I'm trying to set up a preloader but before it starts running the preloader it starts downloading a lot of CSS/js etc files which should not happen since the preloader should run before it starts downloading vue stuff and only stops when the page is ready. This problem is not noticed in fast connections but it's very clear under FAST 3G or SLOW 3G.

I saw some examples using vue routing but I'm routing Vue with flask which means that I shouldn't be able to use the routing way at least that I know.

Is there a way to set it up so it loads the preloader and then starts loading the other stuff in the background?

I'm using vue plugin [Vue-loading-overlay](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-loading-overlay) for the preloader.

Part of my code in case it's necessary:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <vue-topprogress ref="topProgress" :color="'#1d1d25'"
                     :height="5" :errorColor="'#f81732'"/>
    <loading :active.sync="isLoading"
        :is-full-page="true" :opacity="1">
      <img src="../assets/images/testGif.gif" alt="this slowpoke moves"  width=250/>
    </loading>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import Loading from 'vue-loading-overlay';
  import 'vue-loading-overlay/dist/vue-loading.css';

  export default {
    name: 'index',
    components: {
      Loading,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        isLoading: true,
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      document.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      };
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: In my project I've created a main app component with a login page and little JS/CSS. Now the rest of the application with more JS/CSS is in an async component (lazy-loaded), so it loads only when needed (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components)

Comment: @JanMadeyski I read the docs and should I do like a component with the preloader and then use that to load the rest of the page?

Comment: So I understoop the docks but how can I call the component so its loaded after the preloaders is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 solutions: **async route**, and **async component**.

### Async route

Here in the **routes.js** file we define main route `/` with a simple `LoginPage` component which will be included in the main JS bundle file. We also define `/app` route with an async component - this one would be loaded only if user open `/app` route. A comment with `webpackChunkName` tells Webpack to compile that component to another file with that specific name.

**routes.js**

```js
import LoginPage from '../pages/login-page'

const routes = [
 {
  path: '/',
  component: LoginPage
 },
 {
  path: '/app',
  component: () => import('../pages/app-wrapper.vue' /* webpackChunkName: "page--app-wrapper" */),
  children: [
   // child routes
  ]
 }
]
```

Now in Your `login-page` component You can do some stuff, like loading config by AJAX, and then go to `/app` route.

### Async component

Another solution could be using a *dynamic component*. Initially it could be a simple `loaderComponent` and after loading finishes it would become `appWrapperComponent` and only then its definition would be loaded from another bigger chunk file.

```html
<template>
  <div :is="componentName"></div>
</template>
```

```js
export {
  data() {
    componentName: 'loaderComponent'
  },
  components: { loaderComponent },
  mounted() {
    this.$axios('/api/config.json') // its' just an example of loading something
    .then(config => {
      this.$root.config = config; 
      this.componentName = 'appWrapperComponent'; // this changes component name
    });
  }
}
```

Now to make it work we need to make`appWrapperComponent` async.

```js
Vue.component('appWrapperComponent', () => ({
    component: import('../pages/app-wrapper.vue' /* webpackChunkName: "pages--app-wrapper" */),
    delay: 200,
    timeout: 5000
}));
```